# Create new partition with fdisk

Tags: partitioning, vmware, fdisk

I have `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS` (32-bit) running in `VMware Workstation 10.0.3 build-1895310`. I have just modified the Virtual Machine Settings, expanding the Hard Disk from *20 GB* to *30 GB*. So I would like to create a new partition with these extra *10 GB* I just added.

When trying to create a new partition using `fdisk /dev/sda` and `n` as Command, I have to specify the size of this new partition. And I tried the following values:

```
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (2612-3916, default 3916): `10G`
Value out of range.
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (2612-3916, default 3916): `9G`
Value out of range.
Last cylinder, +cylinders or +size{K,M,G} (2612-3916, default 3916): `1M`
Value out of range.
```

When asked what type of partition I would like to create I tried both options, `e` (extended) and `p` (primary), but with no luck. Since not even the `1M` value ain't working.. there must be something I'm missing or doing wrong.. What needs to be done to make it work?

**fdisk /dev/sda** returns this:

```
WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): **p**

Disk /dev/sda: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3916 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0000fba6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          64      512000   83  Linux
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2              64        2611    20458496   8e  Linux LVM
```

Also, **df -h** returns:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_box0-lv_root
                       18G  4.4G   12G  27% /
tmpfs                 503M   76K  503M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   65M  387M  15% /boot
```

Comment: You have to use a + "+10G"

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Oh. You're right. They also did that in the tutorial, but I missed it. You can change you response from comment into  an answer. Many, many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use a + sign when specifying the size.

So for 10 Gb

```
    +10G
```